# .NET MVC - DropDownListFor - selected value differs from Model value

Tags: .net, dropdown, dropdownlistfor

I've read many articles but no solution helped.

I reset a value in controller in model (Model.FileData.ColumnPolicyNumber) from selected (1) to new (0). Then I create new Selectlist with dictionary and new value. The screen shows us that "0" is selected, but browser (Firefox, Chrome too) sets it to "1" again. I even used autocomplete="off" to get rid of automatic set to "1", but it didn't work.

[image]

[image]

Controller work after each request:

```
// clears filled header dropdowns
viewModel.FileData.ColumnClientData = 
viewModel.FileData.ColumnContributionOrInstallmentAmount = 
viewModel.FileData.ColumnPolicyNumber = 
viewModel.FileData.ColumnProvisionAmount = 0;
```

View after each request:

```
@* policy number *@
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FileData.ColumnPolicyNumber, new { @class = "req-field" })
    <span>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.FileData.ColumnPolicyNumber, new SelectList(Model.FileData.HeaderDictionary, "Key", "Value"), new { @class = "form-control", @autocomplete = "off" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FileData.ColumnPolicyNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Does it happen in all browsers, or just FireFox?

Comment: ;) Okay, you updated. So, FireFox & Chrome.

Comment: Please show the full HTML as well as the code which generates your model.

Comment: I added code fragment which clears value (sets to 0), and view generating input.